# How to redirect login page to another page in IFrame?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, iframe

after clicking link button, Modal popUp appears with Iframe which has a login page. Every thing is ok until this. But after write UserName and password i response redirect target page.  But Target page gives me server error: Login.aspx to Target.aspx page return me below error...

[image]

Comment: Can you change your web.config file to show you debug information please, or run it on the webserver and see what error it is giving you.

Comment: Set the custom error mode to off in web config file, this way you will have more details about the error.

Comment: dude, do what @Umar said and post it your brand new error on your question by editing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should required to redirect parent page instead of modal popup in case of iFrame. Here parent would be the page where you have taken iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Internet Explorer v6 or v7 you may need to set http response headers.

Take a look at this item:

[Adam Young's site](http://adamyoung.net/IE-Blocking-iFrame-Cookies)